# How to communicate completion percentage from backend to front end

Tags: node.js, django, webhooks, percentage

Ok so I have a Django backend that performs some tasks and one of the queries computes a complex calculation that can take from a couple of seconds up to 15 minutes based on the entered data.

The point is, I have a loop that I can calculate the completion percentage from however I cant figure out how to send an update query saying something like `{'completion':20}` every loop iteration.

Frontend is Node hosted on a separate server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests should come from the client side. Hold the updated completion value in a model in the backend, send an AJAX request from the client side and ask for the latest completion value, get your response and display it.

Comment: I had this in mind however my model instance this attribute is related to will be initialized after the completion and I was looking if there is a work around other than creating its dedicated model. Anyways thanks for sharing ill be marking this as the answer till something different appears.